# MySql select first rows in every hour, skip rows next 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, select, rows, skip

i'm trying to Select only first Rows from Hour as Example as Datetime optional every 2 Hours/3Hours

```
2020-09-30 09:37:04 SELECT
2020-09-30 09:37:04 SELECT
2020-09-30 09:45:04 SKIP
2020-09-30 09:45:04 SKIP
2020-09-30 09:54:04 SKIP
2020-09-30 10:37:04 SELECT
```

on other Side i think have a Solution, but its not Work.. maybe Wrong Equal to VAR ?

````
SET @prev=0;
SELECT `Date`,@prev, @prev:=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Date`) 
FROM `tab`
WHERE FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Date`)/3600)%2 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`Date`)= @prev;```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tab t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tab 
  where date_format(date, '%Y%m%d%H') = date_format(t.date, '%Y%m%d%H')
    and date < t.date
)
```

or with RANK() window function:

```
select date
from (
  select date,
    rank() over (partition by date_format(date, '%Y%m%d%H') order by date) rnk
  from tab
) t
where t.rnk = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4a1650ef9f21f644148c5c3cfd428c1).
Results:

```
> | date                |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-09-30 09:37:04 |
> | 2020-09-30 09:37:04 |
> | 2020-09-30 10:37:04 |
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great!